# Argument [app.yaml] is not a valid deployable file google cloud error

Tags: shell, gcloud, gcloud-node

I'm going through [the hello world tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world#hello_world_code_review) on how to deploy a nodejs app to google cloud. I downloaded the google cloud sdk. I finished all the steps until "Deploy the app to Google Cloud Platform". When I get there, I enter the command they tell you to enter. It asks if you want to deploy the module and I said yes. Everything is fine until the end where it says

[image]

Is this because my zone is set to us-central-f? I am in India.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: @ZacharyNewman windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your project was created in Europe. Unfortunately Managed VMs don't yet support European projects.

Comment: hey thats if I want to use platform as a service, I can just use infrastructure as a service https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine?hl=en