# How to deploy a nodejs application to google cloud?

Tags: node.js, deployment, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs application to google cloud, I've posted several SO questions about the errors I've been getting and how to fix them. Let me illustrate my endeavours...

[problem 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769233/argument-app-yaml-is-not-a-valid-deployable-file-google-cloud-error) I tried following the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world), the hello world app deployment. When I entered the command to deploy,

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default
```

It gave me an error saying managed vms aren't available for your application's region. I contacted someone from Google, a technical support representative from google, said his name was Ling, and he said he "wasn't aware managed vms weren't supported in India" and he wanted me to point out where I found that information. So I sent him [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769233/argument-app-yaml-is-not-a-valid-deployable-file-google-cloud-error), note one of the answers. OK.....

[problem 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776961/deploying-a-nodejs-app-to-the-google-cloud-platform) So, I was stuck, didn't really know what to do. Searched "how to deploy nodejs app on google cloud" and found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8jZHc0NS6A) in which a google developer informed me that there are "two main ways to run your application in the cloud, infrastructure as a service and platform as a service". Running it on app engine was the platform as a service, and that was off the list so I went with my only remaining option. There is a tutorial, the [bookshelf app](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/tutorial-app) tutorial, also by google, and the last part describes how to run your application on the compute engine. I tried to go through the tutorial, but when I entered the command

```
git push cloud 7-gce:master
```

to push my code to the repository, it's asking me for my username and password, It never mentioned that in the tutorial, I don't know what to enter. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411101/username-and-pass-required-in-git-push-appengine-master) but I'm not sure it applies to my situation. So next I went through some tutorials suggested by Zachary Newman, and I wasn't able to follow [the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) where they use the ubuntu because when they tell you to hello.js file, it's really weird because I had to ssh into the ubuntu image vm I created and everything was really slow, I'm not familiar with commands on linux so I had to look up how to "save and exit" after creating the hello.js file. I got the "web server" to run, it's the reverse proxy nginx server, but since I don't know what the APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS is, when I accessed the page, I could see the nginx page but not the "hello world" message that's supposed to display. Please see the Prerequisites heading to see what the tutorial was trying to teach me. OK....

[problem 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779896/how-to-serve-my-content-with-nodejs-vm-on-google-cloud) On the google developers console, once you log in, there is a navigation section on the left, there is a link to the "Cloud Launcher". In there I found a link to create a Virtual Machine with nodejs installed, it's created by Bitnami. I clicked it and my vm was running, I went to the external ip address provided, and saw a Congratulations (ugh...) page by Bitnami. I didn't really know what to do from there, so I posted another SO question. A bitnami developer told me I "need to copy your files to the remote repository, create the configuration files and after that you have to include that configuration in the configuration of Apache to serve the application". How?!?! He just posted a link as well to a bitnami [wiki page](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Custom_Node.js_Application). I used filezilla to connect to my vm, and I tried to upload my application files to the vm. I was able to upload everything except the node modules (they were taking too long to upload and for some reason the ftp client kept loosing the connection with the server after 10 minutes or so of uploading). So I thought I would just ssh into the instance and try to npm install my dependencies. But it gave me more errors...

[problem 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806819/how-to-ssh-into-a-vm-on-gce-as-the-administrator) I don't know why this post was put on hold, but I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/837996/connecting-to-google-compute-engine-vm-instances). I can't find the exact page right now but I read somewhere in the google docs that we can't ssh into an instance as root/administrator by design, and that we have to perform some advanced configuration in order to be able to do this. THE PROBLEM is that I can't install the dependencies unless I ssh in as an administrator....:'( So I just uploaded my node modules with filezilla. Everything looks good to go, I ssh into my instance and I cd into my application directory and enter the command

```
node app.js
```

and almost as if to taunt me, it console logs out "connected to mongo...." and "Listening on port 3000.....". I get so excited, I think it's working.....

[problem 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807597/how-to-serve-my-own-pages-and-not-the-default-page-on-bitnami-node-server-on-goo) The server never really started running I think, it wasn't able to connect to the mongodb database (another instance) that I was running, this was the command to connect to the mongodb instance in my app.js file

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://****/myappdatabase');
```

where the **** indicates the external IP of my mongodb instances. After about 5 minutes, I get an error on the ssh browser

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ****:27017
```

BUT WHO HAS TIME TO READ ALL OF THIS RIGHT?

I'm not a developer, I don't have much experience with programming (close to zero actually). I'm a hobbyist. I picked up a book on c programming by stephen g. kochan about 5 or 6 months ago, and since then, I've just been following tutorials on the internet, a programming in java book, and some reference material. I wanted to create a website.

I learned some html, css, javascript and jquery off of [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) and went through some tutorials on creating a basic node server and serving some html pages, that's literally all my application does. That's all I want it to do.

I used the express framework for node, and mongoose to connect to my mongodb running locally. Socket.io for a little bit of networking. I created the website for fun and I would really like to host it and share it with my friends, I made it this far, it would be really embarrassing to quit now because I can't host the website. I went through a lot more than what I posted on this question by the way.

Now I would really appreciate some help, even some guidance as to what I need to know, maybe books I should read or documentation I should go through to become more familiar with website hosting would be great. I am going to offer this question up for a bounty in 2 days but until then, if there is anyone that went through this and would like to help for no personal gain of their own, your saving my life. I've been going at this for about 4 days with no luck. Thanks and let me know if there is anything you would like to know about my application. I mean seriously, how hard could it be, I'm doing something (or everything) terribly wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow dude. I thought about flagging this, but you appear to genuinely want to learn to program and need help. And experienced coders teaching novice coders is what this site is all about. So, here we go.

First and foremost, Linux is your friend. Learn it. Use it. I don’t use Ubuntu, but you should. Use 14.04 because it’s a forgiving disto and comes cram-packed with things you need when you’re just learning.

Time to address your questions:

Problem 1: you are using a `gcloud preview` product. Those are awesome, but not for beginners because you don’t know what you’re doing. Just stand up an Ubuntu instance on an n1-standard and rock it. No bells. No whistles. Learn Ubuntu linux with the same passion that you taught yourself how to program a web site.

Problem 2: Don’t use git. I use git every day and it’s awesome, but you have a long way to go and git is hella confusing. Take your workspace, tar/gzip it and just ssh the whole shebang to cloud. Then unzip it and you’ll have your whole code right there on your server. Caveat: never do this professionally. But for someone just learning … small bites dude … small bites.

Problem 3: Don’t use Bitnami pre-built images. It robs you of the opportunity learning how to do this from scratch and that is an invaluable experience. Here are two commands you must learn:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install <insert thing you want to install>
```

That’s it. Not rocket science and you will discover the power of package management on linux.

Problem 4: You are over-thinking this. For real, learn `apt-get`. It will get you so far, you’ll curse yourself for not using it earlier. `apt-get` node. `apt-get` mongo. And slam it all on one instance. Is that what I do professionally? Hell no. But it’s all about baby steps when you combine dev-ops with programming and you need to take those steps.

Errata: You wanted someone to recommend a book or a website or guidance. All you need to know is already on Ubuntu. They are called `man` pages. It’s short for manual. You can buy all the books in the world off Amazon and watch infinite youtube pages. It won’t compare to simply `man`ing commands. You gotta trust me on this.

In summary: Just create an Ubuntu instance. `tar` and `gzip` all your code and `scp` it to your instance. Learn `apt-get` and for real, you are set. You will totally destroy your instance many times. So just delete it, re-create it, and keep starting over. Each time, you will be wiser and smarter than the time before. I tutor novice developers all the time. You gotta start small and work your way up. Eventually you’ll understand why you’d want to use git. Why you want to scale. Why LXC is amazing. Why GCE’s managed instance and VMs are crazy baller, and why scripting your deployment is a best practice. But first you have to understand how to build an instance and get your code there in any way possible. You’ll grow from there. Good luck, buddy.